# htaccess redirect all pages that start with /ee

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

i would like to redirect all users from /ee to another domain example: https://example.com/ee
to https://www.anotherdomain.com

i tried

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.com/ee$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.example2.com [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

but its not working with the "/". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/ee` in your url is an `URL path`   . To check the URL path  You need to match against `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable not the `%{HTTP_HOST}` .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ee
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.example2.com [R=301,L]
```